Is it possible to recreate all algorithms by recreating (non-theoretical omnipotent oracle type) reward function and apply greedy pick each step?
Inspired by Q-Learning: Let's say that we would like to create different approach to algorithms instead following some specific recipe (like applying quicksort to array sorting) we would like to have concrete non-theoretical reward function (even if reward function would have deterministic exponential complexity, we allow different functions for different problems and we would like to have concrete closed form or PDE function not found by neural net approximation) for every problem that can be combined with bellman equation (or some other technique) then taking optimal actions would guarantee to be able to recreate known algorithms? I am most interested in answer is this possible or in the end Q-Learning and other bellman based techniques would have limitations in problem solving. Just for clarification: I am just interested in algorithms that outputs right/optimal answer, and improving means decreasing computation time. Any reference to reading material would be very welcomed even if it wouldn't provide definite answer

The problem is that many real problems are not possible to model that way. For example sorting that you mentioned. What would a reward function look like? It is either "true or false" problem, not "you are 96% correct". Even if you manage to sort 99% of elements, the answer is still "false" or "0". There is no room for gradual improvement, there is no "approximation" to accurate sorting problem. You basically do scan over the space of all algorithms, extremely inefficient. I don't think this is a practical approach for such discontinuous problems.

well Q-Learning and GNN shows promising results... and noone disproved that sorting can't be done by dynamic programming https://www.ijera.com/papers/vol%201%20issue%203/J013446448.pdf and DP can be first step toward this goal. My question is: can it be proven that dynamic programing with Bellman equation has known limitations and can't reproduce or improve over known algorithms (like quicksort)?

As I said: of course it can be done. By scanning entire space of algorithms. The question is not whether this can be done, but whether this can be done efficiently. In my opinion not.
